# SVG marker is not displaying completely

Tags: svg

I'm trying to get an arrow marker to display at the end of a line, but for some reason, this doesn't work in any browser I have or any graphics viewer or editor, except for Inkscape.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500"
  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" refX="-2.33" refY="0" orient="auto">
      <path d="m 0,0 -5,2 q 1.5,-2 0,-4 z"
        style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;"
        transform="scale(0.6667 0.6667)" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(20 20)">
    <path d="m 0,0 100,0" style="stroke-width: 3; marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

**Update**

The right `viewBox` (without scaling the path inside the marker) is `"-5.5 -2.5 6 5"`. The 4 parameters of the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) are min-x, min-y, width, and height. They have to take into account whatever `stroke-width` the `marker`'s elements may have, hence the extra 0.5 that I needed on either side.

Turns out, `markerHeight` and `markerWidth` are important to set, because the default value for both is `3`. That's why the arrow was coming out too small in my earlier attempt. For 1-to-1 scaling, they should be the same as the last two numbers in the `viewBox`.

All of the `viewBox`, `markerHeight`, and `markerWidth` need to be adjusted accordingly when scaling elements inside the marker.

Here's a complete solution based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64490704/2640636) and the comments for posterity:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 30 10" width="300" height="100"
  style="stroke: #000000; fill: none; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" refX="-1.333" refY="0"
      orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth"
      viewBox="-3.667 -1.667 4 3.333"
      markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3.333"
    >
      <path d="m 0,0 -5,2 q 1.5,-2 0,-4 z"
        style="fill: #000000; stroke-width: 1;"
        transform="scale(0.667)"
      />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(5 5)">
    <path d="m 0,0 10,0" style="stroke-width: 1.5; marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(25 5)">
    <path d="m 0,0 -5,2 q 1.5,-2 0,-4 z"
      style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add an `overflow:visible;` to the marker.

Comment: @Blackhole that would be prety poor for performance. Adjusting the marker so it doesn't need that would be better.

Comment: @RobertLongson Indeed, all the more given the fact the the overflow attribute does not work with marker on Chrome, if I remember correctly. But note that the attribute is added automatically by Inkscape for all markers.

Comment: If that's still the case, someone should raise a bug on Inkscape and get it to stop doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is probably to add a viewBox to the marker so the shape is actually drawn in the marker canvas and not outside it.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  viewBox="0 0 500 500" width="500" height="500"
  style="stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill: none; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round;">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" refX="-2.33" refY="0" orient="auto" viewBox="-3 -3 5 5">
      <path d="m 0,0 -5,2 q 1.5,-2 0,-4 z"
        style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); stroke-width: 1;"
        transform="scale(0.6667 0.6667)" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(20 20)">
    <path d="m 0,0 100,0" style="stroke-width: 3; marker-end: url(#arrow);" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `viewBox="-3 -3 5 5"` chops off the tail of the arrow. I tried playing around with the values and found that `viewBox="-5 -2 6 4"` avoids clipping. But now the arrow comes out too small, and if I remove the scaling transformation it's clipped again!

Comment: You probably need to do both i.e. remove the scaling translation and adjust the viewBox then.

Comment: I think I had miscalculated the `viewBox` parameters when I tried earlier.